# css jquery animation with delay between text

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-animate, css-animations

I tried to make an animation, so that when a user opens up my website an animation starts playing.

It should start by showing the first `h1` and then after 1s it should disappear and show the second `h1` and after another 1s, the 2nd `h1` disappears and then it shows the 3rd `h1` and so on. I found the jquery `.delay()` but I couldn't figure out how to use it here. I've got some code already.

I'd be glad if someone could help me out.

```
<div class="intro">
<div class="intro-text">
  <h1 class="intro-text-1">Hi</h1>
  <h1 class="intro-text-2">My</h1>
  <h1 class="intro-text-3">Name</h1>
  <h1 class="intro-text-4">Is</h1>
</div>
```

```
 .intro-text h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: none;
  animation: fadein 2s;
}

@keyframes fadein {
  from {opacity: 0;}
  to {opacity: 1;}
}


$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".intro-text-1").css("display", "block");
//   $(".intro-text-1").delay(2000).css("display", "none");
});
```

But when i tried the .delay() it didn't work.

Comment: `css()` does not perform an animation, by jQuery standards.  jQuery equates "animation" to mean a method that uses it's internal animation queues in order to create the appearance of a native animation.  Since you are not using a jQuery animation, the `delay()` will be ignored.  Ref. http://api.jquery.com/delay/

Answer (score 1):

You can use a timeout to achieve this functionality.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var $introText = $(".intro-text-1");

  $introText.css("display", "block");

  setTimeout(function(){
    $introText.css("display", "none");
  }, 2000);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are getting confused using both CSS and jQuery at the same time.

I would recommend that you either perform this animation strictly using CSS animations, or by using jQuery's methods (but not both).

---

### Using CSS [animation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation)

```css
.intro-text.css h1 {
  opacity: 0;
  animation-name: fadein;
  animation-duration: 2s;
}

@keyframes fadein {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.css .intro-text-1 {
  animation-delay: 0s;
}

.css .intro-text-2 {
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

.css .intro-text-3 {
  animation-delay: 2s;
}

.css .intro-text-4 {
  animation-delay: 3s;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="intro-text css">
  <h1 class="intro-text-1">Hi</h1>
  <h1 class="intro-text-2">My</h1>
  <h1 class="intro-text-3">Name</h1>
  <h1 class="intro-text-4">Is</h1>
</div>
```

---

### Using jQuery [.animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

```js
$(function() {


  $(".intro-text.js h1").each(function(index) {
    $(this).css('opacity', 0);
    $(this).delay(1000 * index).animate({
      opacity: 1
    }, 2000, function() {
      $(this).css('opacity', 0)
    });
  });

})
```

```css
h1 {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.js" integrity="sha256-1XMpEtA4eKXNNpXcJ1pmMPs8JV+nwLdEqwiJeCQEkyc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="intro-text js">
  <h1 class="intro-text-1">Hi</h1>
  <h1 class="intro-text-2">My</h1>
  <h1 class="intro-text-3">Name</h1>
  <h1 class="intro-text-4">Is</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to add to @Taplar's answer by taking advantage of `setInterval` letting the function loop through the children of `.intro-text` on it's own:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var intros = $(".intro-text").children();
    var index = 0;
    setInterval(function(){
        if(index < intros.length){
            intros.hide();
            $(intros[index]).show();
            index++;
        }
    }, 1000)
});
```